# Нет перевода фразы "declined in the last 7 days" в истории тревог

Tags: дефект, локализация, история-тревог

Нет перевода фразы в истории тревог:

[image: declined in the last 7 days]

(`declined in the last 7 days`)

Предлагаю перевод: **отменённые за последние 7 дней**

Comment: отклонённые . . .

Comment: @Эникейщик не велика разница.

Comment: Велика. Это совершенно разные вещи. Отменяешь сам, а отклоняют другие.

Comment: @Эникейщик такой же аргумент: Отклоняешь сам, отменяют другие. Всё равно не вижу разницы.

Comment: конечно же не такой. Это аргумент от неграмотности. Другие могут, конечно, отменить. Но отклонить **свое** действие нельзя. Это неграмотно. Можно только отменить (ну или забрать назад, например, еще, если речь о словах).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

> declined in the last 7 days 
> отклонённые за последние 7 дней
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11052

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.